# Visual Studio 2019 - can't change profile settings, opens FolderProfile.pubxml instead

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2019.
From what I have seen in tutorials, during publishing an application, I should be able to change profile settings, by clicking a small pencil (I included a screenshot, it's a little pencil next to "false" and other settings.) However, every time i click it, it opens FolderProfile.pubxml file in Visual Studio instead! Is this indended behaviour, am I doing something completely wrong? How to change that? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH3VH.png)

Answer (score 0):

My problem fixed when I updated visual studio.
Also go to extensions and update all.
Now show UI options.

[image: Screenshot]